# What is the origin of "TX" as an abbreviation for "transaction"?

Tags: etymology, abbreviations

Acronymfinder.com [lists TX as a rare abbreviation for "transaction"](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Transaction-(TX).html), particularly in the context of computers. It use by [the Bitcoin protocol](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#tx) may be its best-known application, but I've also found a [few](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Fuse_ESB_Enterprise/7.1/html/EIP_Transaction_Guide/files/XaUser-Annotation.html) [other](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html) instances. As the Acronym Finder suggests, it seems to be used sparingly at best, and I've found no non-technology-related uses of it.

Does anybody know of an origin or first use of abbreviating "transaction" as "tx"?

Comment: Sometimes it's also TXN.

Comment: I have seen this in the context of older (think 1990's, e.g. Great Plains) computer implementations of accounting systems a number of times, for instance as the first two characters of transaction references, the remaining characters being digits.

Comment: Medicine has a tendency to abbreviate many things using X: Biopsy - Bx, Dx - diagnosis, Fx - fracture, Hx - history, Sx - surgery, and Tx - transplant, transformation, transaction, therapy, treatment (though transaction is not the most common of terms in medicine).

Comment: I'll note that "X" is a common way to abbreviate "trans", as in "xmit" for "transmit".  But somewhere along the way the X got twisted to where some writers/coders use "TX" for "transmit" and "RX" for "receive".

Comment: See also [this Q on Rx](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/rx-for-prescriptions), [this on Rx/Sx/etc](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/314546/term-for-the-second-letter-in-sx-dx-rx), and lots of other questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I will go with @undefined: the abbreviation [TX](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=TX&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CTX%3B%2Cc0) for internet transaction is borrowed from telegraph abbreviation for transmission, [Tx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_(telecommunications)), for an internet [transaction](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transaction) involves sending a coded signal from my computer to , say Amazon.com, internet site.

Answer (score 6):

In the old days amateur radio operators, who abbreviated wildly because they were using Morse code keys to exchange information, used to use XCVR as transceiver and XMTR as transmitter.  A lot of older programmers also have amateur radio licenses so they probably just continued the tradition.  I cannot begin to guess how you would ever find the first use of TX, but I would bet it's everywhere in early data communication standards documentation.

Answer (score 6):

I have no evidence to support this answer, so feel free to downvote it, but this might help:

The *X*, itself, stands for *trans* (see also the answer by @undefined, with examples). I believe (again, I don't have proof) that this comes from the association of *trans* with its meaning of *across* (hence, a cross).

A guess (only a guess) would be that *TX* is related to this use of *X*.