# Term for the second letter in Sx, Dx, Rx?

Tags: terminology, abbreviations

In abbreviations such as Dx (diagnosis), Sx (symptom), and Rx (prescription), is there a specific term for the second letter in the abbreviation?

I have tried to google this but end up with results explaining the meaning of the abbreviations, rather than the specific term for the "x".

Comment: Just to be clear, "Rx" is just a modern typographic approximation to the original symbol, ℞, which is just an R (for *recipe*) with a stroke through its right leg. That is, originally, there was no "x". Thus, I think you're unlikely to find a specific name for it. I did a little digging to see if there was a specific name for the stroke through the leg, but cursory research revealed the origins of the symbol are lost to history. There have been a few theories advanced, but they whiff of folk etymology to me. In re: Dx, Sx, I imagine these were modeled after Rx.

Comment: See here also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83658/what-do-the-letters-dx-of-diagnosis-stand-for?noredirect=1#comment164242_83658

Comment: There are two separate things that this question could be about, either the specific shape/letterform/glyph that's the right hand side of the Rx, or an abstract noun for the practice of using an x ("xification"?). As far as I can tell as a typographic symbol it's just a lowercase x. If typesetting you either use a single glyph for "Rx" which joins the letters (“℞” U+211E Prescription Take Unicode Character), or you use standard uppercase-R and lowercase-x. Why should it have a name any more than the "g" in the abbreviation "e.g." or the cross in an ampersand&?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems plausible that the medical convention of using 'x' as the second letter of an abbreviation (in, for example, *Dx* (*diagnosis*), *Sx* (*symptom* or *surgery*), *Fx* (*family*), *Hx* (*history*), and *Tx* (*transplant* or *treatment*)) comes from copying the convention of using *Rx* as an abbreviation of *prescription*.

*Rx* is, as Dan Bron observed in his comment, most likely an approximation of the Latin '℞', which is an 'R' with a slashed leg. The 'R' stands for *recipe*, the Latin translation of the imperative *take* ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medical_prescription)). Another, more dubious, etymology links it to the Egyptian eye of Horus or the Greek symbol for Zeus.

From the research I could find, nobody knows anything specific about this symbol.

I did discover, however, that Latin scribes had special abbreviations called ***sigla*** ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation)). Sometimes scribes would *suspend* words, which means that they would cut off their ends, often showing only the first letter. When scribes did this, they would mark the abbreviations with special suspension symbols (see the Wikipeida section on "specific suspension", [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation)).

It seems very likely (to me at least) that the slash through the leg of the 'R' was precisely such a marking. After all, it resembles some of the suspension sigla Wikipedia shows:

[image]

As to the question or whether or not there's a specific name for the symbol 'x' as it appears in medical abbreviations, there is. Unfortunately, the name is just 'x'.